# Umbrella academy reading order

Tags: suggested-order, the-umbrella-academy

What is the suggested reading order for the comic books of Umbrella academy?

I found the Hazel and ChaCha save christmas on a good deal and bought it before even receiving the Apocalypse Suite series.

Where in the storyline does it fit?